# Implicit differentiation and linear approximations

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation, linear-approximation

Consider the implicit function $$(w(x)+1)e^{w(x)}=x.$$ I need to approximate $w(1.1)$ using the fact that  $w(1)=0$.

Could you give me any hints?

Comment: What happens when you take the derivative with respect to $x$ and then let $x=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the implicit equation $$F=(y+1)e^y-x=0$$ and compute the partial derivatives $$F'_x=-1$$ $$F'_y= (y+2)e^y$$ Now, from implicit differentiation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=\frac 1 {(y+2)e^y}$$ So $$y(1.1)\approx y(1)+\frac {1.1-1.0} {(y(1)+2)e^{y(1)}}=0+\frac {0.1} {(0+2)e^{0}}=0.05$$

You could also compute $\frac{dx}{dy}$ and deduce $\frac{dy}{dx}$ from it. This is probably the simplest.